# No consigo que me enseñe los datos enviados

Tags: php

Esta es la página formulario

```
<HEAD>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <TITLE> Formulario </TITLE>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
        function confirmExit()
        {
            return "Ha intentado salir de esta pagina. Si ha realizado algun cambio en los campos sin hacer clic en el boton Guardar, los cambios se perderan. Seguro que desea salir de esta pagina? ";
        }
        var table1_inputs=0;
        function myCreateFunction()
        {
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            var row = table.insertRow(2);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
            var input1= document.createElement("textarea");
                input1.rows="4";
                input1.cols="170";
                table1_inputs++;
                input1.name= 'name1'+table1_inputs;
                input1.id = 'id1'+table1_inputs;
            var campo4 = document.createElement("input");
                campo4.type = "button";
                campo4.value = "Borrar";
                campo4.onclick = function ()
                    {
                        var fila = this.parentNode.parentNode;
                        var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
                        tbody.removeChild(fila);
                    }
            cell2.appendChild(input1);
            cell2.appendChild(campo4);
        }

        function vaciar_campo(input1)
        {
            input1.value = "";
        }
        var table2_inputs=0;
        function myCreateFunction2()
        {
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable2");
            var row = table.insertRow(2);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
            var input2 = document.createElement("textarea");
                input2.rows="4";
                input2.cols="170";
                table2_inputs++;
                input2.name = 'name2'+table2_inputs;
                input2.id = 'id2'+table2_inputs;
            var campo4 = document.createElement("input");
                campo4.type = "button";
                campo4.value = "Borrar";
                campo4.onclick = function ()
                    {
                        var fila = this.parentNode.parentNode;
                        var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
                        tbody.removeChild(fila);
                    }
            cell2.appendChild(input2);
            cell2.appendChild(campo4);
        }

        function vaciar_campo(input2)
        {
            input2.value = "";
        }
        var table3_inputs=0;
        function myCreateFunction3()
        {
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable3");
            var row = table.insertRow(2);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
            var input3 = document.createElement("textarea");
                input3.rows="4";
                input3.cols="170";
                table3_inputs++;
                input3.name = 'name3'+table3_inputs;
                input3.id = 'id3'+table3_inputs;
            var campo4 = document.createElement("input");
                campo4.type = "button";
                campo4.value = "Borrar";
                campo4.onclick = function ()
                    {
                        var fila = this.parentNode.parentNode;
                        var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
                        tbody.removeChild(fila);
                    }
            cell2.appendChild(input3);
            cell2.appendChild(campo4);
        }

        function vaciar_campo(input3)
        {
            input.value = "";
        }
        var table4_inputs=0;
        function myCreateFunction4()
        {
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable4");
            var row = table.insertRow(2);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
            var input4 = document.createElement("textarea");
                input4.rows="4";
                input4.cols="170";
                table4_inputs++;
                input4.name = 'name4'+table4_inputs;
                input4.id = 'id4'+table4_inputs;
            var campo4 = document.createElement("input");
                campo4.type = "button";
                campo4.value = "Borrar";
                campo4.onclick = function ()
                    {
                        var fila = this.parentNode.parentNode;
                        var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
                        tbody.removeChild(fila);
                    }
            cell2.appendChild(input4);
            cell2.appendChild(campo4);
        }

        function vaciar_campo(input4)
        {
            input.value = "";
        }
    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <form name="formulario" id="formulario" action="creador.php" method="post" width="30%">
        <table id="myTable" border="3" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h1>
                                Tesis Doctoral
                            </h1>
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <textarea  name="Tesis" id="Tesis" rows="4" cols="170"></textarea>
                            <button onclick="myCreateFunction()" type="button" name="Tesis2" id="Tesis2">
                                Añadir
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table id="myTable2" border="3" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h1>
                                Subvenciones
                            </h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <textarea  name="Subvenciones" id="Subvenciones" rows="4" cols="170"></textarea>
                            <button onclick="myCreateFunction2()" type="button" name="Subvenciones2" id="Subvenciones2">
                                Añadir
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table id="myTable3" border="3" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h1>
                                Otra informacion
                            </h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <textarea  name="Otrainfo" id="Otrainfo" rows="4" cols="170"></textarea>
                            <button onclick="myCreateFunction3()" type="button" name="Otrainfo2" id="Otrainfo2">
                                Añadir
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table id="myTable4" border="3" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h1>
                                Actualidad
                            </h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <textarea  name="Actualidad" id="Actualidad" rows="4" cols="170"></textarea>
                            <button onclick="myCreateFunction4()" type="button" name="actualidad2" id="actualidad2">
                                Añadir
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <center>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </center>
    </form>
 </BODY>
```

Esta es la página recipiente

```
 <?php

  $html = '<html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            <title>"Boletín informativo semanal de la Facultad de Veterinaria, Universidad de Zaragoza"</title>
            <link rel=themeData href="BOL%20MODELO_archivos/themedata.thmx">
            <link rel=colorSchemeMapping href="BOL%20MODELO_archivos/colorschememapping.xml">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/estilos.css">
            <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
        </head>
        <body bgcolor=whitesmoke lang=ES link=blue vlink=purple style="tab-interval:35.4pt">
            <div class=WordSection1>

                <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%"
                 style="width:100.0%;mso-cellspacing:0cm;background:whitesmoke;mso-yfti-tbllook:
                 1184;mso-padding-alt:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                 <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes">
                  <td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                  <table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
                   style="mso-cellspacing:0cm;background:white;border-top:none;border-left:
                   solid #E7E7E7 1.0pt;border-bottom:none;border-right:solid #E7E7E7 1.0pt;
                   mso-border-left-alt:solid #E7E7E7 .75pt;mso-border-right-alt:solid #E7E7E7 .75pt;
                   mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0cm 7.5pt 0cm 7.5pt">
                   <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes;
                    height:576.85pt">
                    <td style="border:none;padding:0cm 7.5pt 0cm 7.5pt;height:576.85pt">
                    <div style="margin-left:11.25pt;margin-top:30.0pt">
                    <p class=MsoNormal><span style="mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
                    mso-no-proof:yes"><img width=508 height=139 id="_x0000_i1025"
                    src="http://veterinaria.unizar.es/sites/veterinaria.unizar.es/files/centros_logos_web-11.png"
                    alt="http://veterinaria.unizar.es/sites/veterinaria.unizar.es/files/centros_logos_web-11.png"></span><span
                    style="mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman""><o:p></o:p></span></p>
                    <p style="margin-top:3.75pt"><span style="font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
                    color:#223D71">Boletín informativo semanal de la <strong><span
                    style="font-family:"Arial","sans-serif"">Facultad de Veterinaria de la
                    Universidad de Zaragoza</span></strong><o:p></o:p></span></p>
                    </div>
                    <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%"
                     style="width:100.0%;mso-cellspacing:1.5pt;background:#999999;mso-yfti-tbllook:
                     1184;mso-padding-alt:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt">
                     <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes">
                      <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
                      <p style="margin-top:1.5pt;margin-right:11.25pt;margin-bottom:1.5pt;
                      margin-left:11.25pt"><span style="font-size:8.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
                      color:whitesmoke">Está recibiendo este mensaje como miembro de la lista
                      de distribución ESTUDIANTES/PDI/PAS de la Facultad de Veterinaria de la
                      Universidad de Zaragoza. Si no ve correctamente este mensaje o bien desea
                      acceder a BOLETINES ANTERIORES pulse <a
                      href="http://veterinaria.unizar.es/boletín-0" target="_blank"><span
                      style="color:#1B1B1B;text-decoration:none;text-underline:none">AQUÍ</span></a><o:p></o:p></span></p>
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                    </table>
                    <p class=MsoNormal><span style="mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
                    display:none;mso-hide:all"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                    <table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
                     width="100%" style="width:100.0%;mso-cellspacing:0cm;border:none;
                     border-top:solid white 1.5pt;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                     <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes">
                      <td style="border:none;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                      <table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellpadding=0 width="100%"
                       style="width:100.0%;mso-cellspacing:1.5pt;border:dotted #DADADA 1.0pt;
                       mso-border-alt:dotted #DADADA .75pt;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:
                       0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt">
                       <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes">
                        <td style="border:none;padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
                        <p class=style2 style="margin-top:1.5pt;margin-right:11.25pt;
                        margin-bottom:1.5pt;margin-left:11.25pt"><strong><span
                        style="font-family:"Arial","sans-serif"">fecha</span></strong></p>
                        </td>
                        <td style="border:none;padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
                        <p class=style1 style="margin-top:1.5pt;margin-right:11.25pt;
                        margin-bottom:1.5pt;margin-left:11.25pt"><strong><span
                        style="font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:#C00000">Nº 1045</span></strong></p>
                        </td>
                       </tr>
                      </table>
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                    </table>
                    <p class=MsoNormal><span style="mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
                    display:none;mso-hide:all"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                    <table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
                     width="100%" style="width:100.0%;mso-cellspacing:0cm;border:none;
                     border-top:solid white 6.0pt;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                     <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes">
                      <td style="border:none;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                      <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%"
                       style="width:100.0%;mso-cellspacing:1.5pt;background:#007E01;mso-yfti-tbllook:
                       1184;mso-padding-alt:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt">
                       <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes">
                        <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
                        <p class=nombre-categoria>TESIS DOCTORAL</p>
                        </td>
                       </tr>
                      </table>
                      <p class=MsoNormal><span style="mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
                      display:none;mso-hide:all"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                      <table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
                       width="100%" style="width:100.0%;mso-cellspacing:0cm;border:none;
                       border-bottom:dotted #DADADA 1.0pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:dotted #DADADA .75pt;
                       mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                       <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes">
                        <td style="border:none;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span style="mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                        <ul style="margin-top:0cm" type=disc>
                         <li class=MsoNormal style="margin-right:11.35pt;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1;
                             tab-stops:list 36.0pt"><span style="font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
                             mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman""><?php echo $_POST["Tesis"]; ?></span>
                        </li>
                        </ul>

                        <p class=MsoNormal style="margin-top:0cm;margin-right:11.35pt;
                        margin-bottom:0cm;margin-left:17.85pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt"><span
                        style="font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                        <p class=MsoListParagraph><span style="mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                        </td>
                       </tr>
                      </table>
                      <p class=MsoNormal><span style="mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
                      display:none;mso-hide:all"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                      <table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
                       width="100%" style="width:100.0%;mso-cellspacing:0cm;border:none;
                       border-top:solid white 6.0pt;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                       <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes">
                        <td style="border:none;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                        <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%"
                         style="width:100.0%;mso-cellspacing:1.5pt;background:#007E01;
                         mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt">
                         <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:
                          yes">
                          <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
                          <p class=nombre-categoria>SUBVENCIONES / BECAS</p>
                          </td>
                         </tr>
                        </table>
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span style="mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
                        display:none;mso-hide:all"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                        <table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
                         width="100%" style="width:100.0%;mso-cellspacing:0cm;border:none;
                         border-bottom:dotted #DADADA 1.0pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:dotted #DADADA .75pt;
                         mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                         <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:
                          yes">
                          <td style="border:none;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                          <p class=MsoNormal><span style="mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                          //aqui va el segundo texto <----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                          <ul style="margin-top:0cm" type=disc>
                           <li class=MsoNormal style="margin-right:11.35pt;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1;
                               tab-stops:list 36.0pt"><span style="font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
                               mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"">$datos2</span></li>
                          </ul>
                          <p class=MsoNormal style="margin-top:0cm;margin-right:11.35pt;
                          margin-bottom:0cm;margin-left:17.85pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt"><span
                          style="font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>

                          <p class=MsoNormal style="margin-top:0cm;margin-right:11.35pt;
                          margin-bottom:0cm;margin-left:17.85pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt"><span
                          style="font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                          <p class=MsoListParagraph><span style="font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
                          mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                          <p class=MsoNormal style="margin-top:0cm;margin-right:11.35pt;
                          margin-bottom:0cm;margin-left:17.85pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt"><span
                          style="mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                          </td>
                         </tr>
                        </table>
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span style="mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
                        display:none;mso-hide:all"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                        <table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
                         width="100%" style="width:100.0%;mso-cellspacing:0cm;border:none;
                         border-top:solid white 6.0pt;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:
                         0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                         <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:
                          yes">
                          <td style="border:none;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                          <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%"
                           style="width:100.0%;mso-cellspacing:1.5pt;background:#007E01;
                           mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt">
                           <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:
                            yes">
                            <td style="padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
                            <p class=nombre-categoria>OTRAS INFORMACIONES</p>
                            </td>
                           </tr>
                          </table>
                          <p class=MsoNormal><span style="mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
                          display:none;mso-hide:all"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                          <table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
                           width="100%" style="width:100.0%;mso-cellspacing:0cm;border:none;
                           border-bottom:dotted #DADADA 1.0pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:dotted #DADADA .75pt;
                           mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                           <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:
                            yes">
                            <td style="border:none;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                            // aqui va el tercer parrafo <-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            <p class=MsoNormal><span style="mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                            <ul style="margin-top:0cm" type=disc>
                             <li class=MsoNormal style="margin-right:11.35pt;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1;
                                 tab-stops:list 36.0pt"><span style="font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
                                 mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"">$datos3</span></li>
                            </ul>
                            <p class=MsoNormal style="margin-top:0cm;margin-right:11.35pt;
                            margin-bottom:0cm;margin-left:17.85pt;margin-bottom:.0001pt"><span
                            style="font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:
                            "Times New Roman""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                            <ul style="margin-top:0cm" type=disc>
                             <ul style="margin-top:0cm" type=circle>
                              <li class=MsoNormal style="margin-right:11.35pt;mso-list:l0 level2 lfo1;
                                  tab-stops:list 72.0pt"><span class=SpellE><span
                                  style="font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:
                                  "Times New Roman"">$datos4</span></span><span style="font-family:
                                  "Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman""><o:p></o:p></span></li>
                              <li class=MsoNormal style="margin-right:11.35pt;mso-list:l0 level2 lfo1;
                                  tab-stops:list 72.0pt"><span style="font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
                                  mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"">DSAFDS<o:p></o:p></span></li>
                              <li class=MsoNormal style="margin-right:11.35pt;mso-list:l0 level2 lfo1;
                                  tab-stops:list 72.0pt"><span style="font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
                                  mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"">SFDADSF<o:p></o:p></span></li>
                             </ul>
                            </ul>

                            </td>
                           </tr>
                          </table>
                          <p class=MsoNormal><span style="mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
                          display:none;mso-hide:all"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
                          <table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
                           width="100%" style="width:100.0%;mso-cellspacing:0cm;border:none;
                           border-top:solid white 4.5pt;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:
                           0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                           <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:
                            yes">
                            <td style="border:none;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm">
                            <p class=MsoNormal><span style="mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"">&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p>
                            </td>
                           </tr>
                          </table>
                          <p class=MsoNormal><span style="font-size:10.0pt;mso-fareast-font-family:
                          "Times New Roman""><o:p></o:p></span></p>
                          </td>
                         </tr>
                        </table>
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span style="font-size:10.0pt;mso-fareast-font-family:
                        "Times New Roman""><o:p></o:p></span></p>
                        </td>
                       </tr>
                      </table>
                      <p class=MsoNormal><span style="font-size:10.0pt;mso-fareast-font-family:
                      "Times New Roman""><o:p></o:p></span></p>
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                    </table>
                    <p class=MsoNormal><span style="font-size:10.0pt;mso-fareast-font-family:
                    "Times New Roman""><o:p></o:p></span></p>
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                  </table>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
                </table>
                <?php
                echo datos1
                ?>
                <p class=MsoNormal><span style="mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>

                </div>

        </body>
    </html>';
 file_put_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba2\Pagfinal.html', $html);
 ?>
```

y así es como lo recibo.

> 

pero no me muestra nada

Comment: Hola. ¿Puedes indicar cuál es el error que te da tu código? ¿Cómo debería funcionar? ¿Qué soluciones has intentado?

Comment: Yo no veo código php por ningun lado, ¿está bien etiquetada la pregunta?. Da la impresión de que ambos códigos son **iguales**

Comment: Si, disculpa cuando metí el código coloqué la misma sinquerer, he intentado cambiarlo e intentarlo con get, he intentado hacerlo por javascript, y he intentado con el metodo de fopen fwrite/fput y guardarlo pero de ninguna manera.

Comment: Antes pregunté ¿Cómo debería funcionar? Resulta que en el `file_put_contents()` de la última línea de tu código estás escribiendo en un archivo (Pagfinal.html) el código que está al inicio de tu recipiente (la variable `$html`). Estás **escribiendo**, nada más. Por eso, veo normal que ese código no muestre nada en pantalla.

Comment: Si, claro pero el archivo que me crea me muestra todo menos los datos introducidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes una doble apertura de php tags en la forma

```
<?php
$html = '<html>..... <?php echo datos ?> </html>';
```

Dentro de ese `<?php echo datos ?>` en vez de hacer referencia a una variable `$datos` estarías tratando de imprimir una constante llamada `datos`, que intuyo no existe.

Corrigiendo ambos problemas, eso debiera ser, en cambio

```
$html = '<html>..... ';
$html .= $datos;
$html .= '...</html>';
```

Y eso obviamente no lo verías en pantalla pero sí iría al archivo que estás creando. (a menos que hicieras un `echo $html` al final).

En segundo lugar, no explicas de donde sale $datos. Si tu formulario se envía con POST, lo que reciben del otro lado tienes que capturarlo con `$_POST`

```
  $Tesis = $_POST['Tesis'];
  $Subvenciones = $_POST['Subvenciones'];
  $Otrainfo = $_POST['Otrainfo'];
  $Actualidad = $_POST['Actualidad'];
```

Pero además tu formulario tiene campos variables que se llaman

- name11
- name23
- name41

etc etc.

Por lo que imagino tendrías que capturar el post con algo como

```
$datos = $_POST;
```

En donde $datos sería un array asociativo. Y dado que `$datos` es un array asociativo, entonces interpolarlo en medio de tu variable `$html` no tiene mucho sentido. Más bien debiera ser:

```
$html = '<html>..... ';
foreach($datos as $nombre => $valor) {
   $html .= '<br>'.$nombre.' : '.$datos;
}
$html .= '...</html>';
```

Comment: Vale, si muchas gracias lo he solucionado ya.